# How can I access articles from my school newspaper website and update my app when a new one is posted?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My school newspaper recently switched from print to digital, and I wanted to make an app so that the newspaper is more accessible.

As of right now, students can only access it via [this](http://vikinglogue.com/) website, and articles are largely ignored because no one bothers to check it.

I have a moderate amount of experience with making apps in Swift (through bitfountain and Ray Wenderlich), but I'm not sure how to start this project. If possible, how can I fetch articles from the website above and display them on an app? As of now, I'm not looking to mimic the site with a sports feed, comment sections, polls, etc, but I do want to be able to:

- Get the text of the article, as well as the title, author, and date
- Get the category that the article is filed under (News, Sports, Features, etc)
- Get the picture(s) included in the article (this is not crucial)

I'm really stumped on how I can access this information and create an app that can continually fetch new articles when they are posted and update itself to show them. Is this a feasible endeavor, and if so, how can I start?

Comment: A simple RSS feed could do the trick. http://vikinglogue.com/feed/

Comment: Cool! Sorry, I'm still a bit of a newbie at this; could you direct me to a place where I can learn how to interpret/use the RSS feed inside my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post from W3schools. This is a PHP script that grabs the feed url and renders it in HTML.

I think this will be perfect for your project.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp